# How dense is the set of rational points of a variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rational-points, projective-varieties

General question: Let $W$ be a proper subvariety of an irreducible affine variety $V/K$. Under what conditions do we know that $W(K)$ is a proper subset of $V(K)$?

If $K$ is finite, then one can bound $|W(K)|$ by $\ll_{\deg(W)} |K|^{\dim(W)}$. (Here we write $|S|$ for the number of elements of a set $S$.) If one can give a bound of the form $|V(K)|\gg |K|^{\dim(V)}$, it then follows that $|W(K)|<|V(K)|$ provided that $K$ is large enough in terms of the degree of $W$.

When can one prove something similar for $K$ infinite? The condition that needs to be replaced here is $|V(K)|\gg |K|^{\dim(V)}$. Things work out if one assumes that $V$ is unirational, but that feels a bit stronger than needed; is a weaker condition enough? What would the proof then be?

(Obviously one needs some sort of condition, as is shown by the example of $V$ given by $x^2+y^2 = 0$, $W$ the zero-dimensional variety $x,y=0$, and $K = \mathbb{R}$.)

Also: is there any sort of model-theoretical transfer principle that one might hope would work here? In which direction would it go - $K$ finite to $K$ infinite, or $K$ infinite to $K$ finite?

Comment: Is it important to you that the variety is irreducible but not necessarily geometrically irreducible?

Comment: @ArnoFehm I put in the condition of irreducibility just to ensure that $W$ is of positive codimension. Why do you ask?

Comment: Well, probably this is clear to you, but for geometrically irreducible varieties over finite fields you get a positive answer from the Lang-Weil estimates, which then transfers to ultraproducts, i.e. pseudo-finite fields. More generally, you get a positive answer (for geometrically irreducible varieties) over pseudo-algebraically closed fields. If we add the assumption that $V$ is smooth and $V(K)$ nonempty, then you get a positive answer for many other fields, including $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Right, Lang-Weil is enough over finite fields. How does one get the answer over pseudo-algebraically closed fields? And how does smoothness help?

Comment: Well, over a pseudo-algebraically closed field, by definition every (nonempty, geom. irred.) variety has a rational point, so in particular the variety $V\setminus W$ has one. Over so-called large fields $K$ (which include for example $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}_p$) every variety with a regular $K$-rational point has a Zariski-dense set of $K$-rational points, so in particular if $V$ is smooth and $V(K)\neq\emptyset$, then $V(K)\setminus W(K)\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: For $\mathbb{R}$ for example this is just the implicit function theorem: Any smooth rational point on $W$ gives a whole Euclidean neighborhood of rational points, in particular many in $V\setminus W$.